# Applying Kelly Criterion to profit/loss bet

Tags: probability, gambling

In a financial derivative trading situation, there are two outcomes to a bet (win/lose), but I don't necessarily lose my entire stake if I lose the bet, because I can buy my way out of the bet, taking a net loss. Nonetheless, I have to bet the entire stake in order to play. However, if I win the bet, I receive my stake plus a fraction as a gain.

For example, let's say:

- my bankroll is \$100
- if I win, I will gain 5% of my stake
- if I lose, I will lose 30% of my stake
- I expect to win 91% of the time

What I want to determine is how much of my bankroll to put at stake.

According the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion) article, I should be using this formula:

$$
f*=(\frac pa)-(\frac qb)
$$

where:

- p = probability of winning
- q = probability of losing ($\equiv 1-p$)
- a = amount of loss
- b = amount of gain
- f* = percentage of bankroll to bet

However, when I do the math:

$$
f*=(\frac{.91}{.3})-(\frac{.09}{.05})={3.0\overline3}-{1.8}={1.2\overline3}
$$

That's obviously very wrong. I'm expecting a number where $0 \leq f* \leq 1$.

A colleague provided a function that he claims is a Kelly formula, and it gives values that I would expect, but I don't understand how he got the formula he uses.

$$
k*=p-\frac q{(\frac ba)}
$$

The math works closer to what I would expect:

$$
k*={0.91}-\frac {0.09}{(\frac {.05}{.3})}={0.91}-\frac {0.09}{.1\overline6}={0.91}-{.54}={.37}
$$

So I would put 37% of my bankroll at stake, which seems about right.

What I don't understand is how my colleague's math works to the Kelly Criterion, or how I misapplied the formula from Wikipedia.

Comment: Wikipedia's formula is correct. Since the bet is heavily favored in your direction, you should *borrow* money and bet $1.2\bar 3$ of your current wealth and return the loan after the bet settles. This is an example of how using leverage can be optimal for a "sure-bet" investment. You can introduce "cost of the loan" $r$ (interest rate) which would reduce your optimal investment.

Comment: @A.S. I think I understand. In my case, it just means I'd bet the entire bankroll (I'm personally not interested in leveraging right now). And, because it's not a complete loss of my stake if I do lose, I don't risk gambler's ruin, correct?

Comment: Correct. Your colleague's formula is $k*=af*$ which is not dimensionally correct and is obviously wrong for $a=0$ (lose nothing so bet as much as you can).

Comment: In terms of dimensional analysis, while all quantities are dimensionless, $f*,a,b$ are ratios of money values while $p,q$ are ratios of "chances" (truly dimensionless, so to say) so $f*=p-q(a/b)$ can't be correct.

Comment: That explains it. If you would like to take credit for the answer, I'll need you to add something as an answer.

Comment: BTW I expect that $a$ and $b$ are non-zero in practice. I'd never bet on anything that had no gain ($b = 0$). There's clearly no risk if there was nothing to lose ($a = 0$), so I'd bet everything. Those are special cases I don't need the Kelly Criterion for.

Comment: True, but if you want to check correctness of the formula obtained, it's always wise to consider boundary scenarios where the answer can be reasoned out without computation as it can quickly eliminate wrong answers.